# Android 5.0 build number not shown in Settings > About Phone

Tags: android, usb-debugging

I have purchased QMobile S1 which has Android 5.0 running.

I am trying to enable developer options but I can't find Build Number in About Phones in Settings. I know I need to tap on Build Number 7 times to become a developer. But the option is not even shown in the About Phone.

I tried taping Android Version in About Phone which showed me animation of Lollipop.

How can I make it appear?

This is how my About Phone screen looks.

[image]

Comment: Try to get in touch with the manufacturer. This seems to be a problem specific to this phone.

Comment: I have also sent an email to manufacturer. Waiting for there reply... isn't there any hack?

Answer (score 2):

If you arrive here, search for `build number` and you'll turn up the location. It appears to have been moved to:
About device -> Software Info

Answer (score 0):

The Settings App on my Android phone (Android 6.0.1, MIUI 10 Global 9.3.28 Beta) doesn't show the build number either. Not under "About device", nor under "About device -> Software Info" or anything similar.
I solved the problem by downloading an app from Play Store, called "Developer Options". Using that app I could easily switch on and off the developer options and USB debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the different Android versions or the phone versions, but on different phones, it may be at different locations. Instead of "Build number" it might be "Software version" on some phones.

Most Android phones:

> “Settings”>”About”>Tap ”Build Number” 7 times quickly or more.

Other android phones:

> "Settings">"System Management">"About Phone">Tap "Software version" 7
> times quickly or more.

Just tap anything in "About" that has "build number" or "software info" or "software version" in it, as different phones seem to have different locations.

In your case, it appears that you want to tap the "Software version" in your screenshot 7 times.